# Find integral limits for step functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, algorithms, step-function

I have an equation of the form

$$f(t) + \int_0^t H(t') dt' = c$$.

For now, assume that $f(t)$ is linear, and $H(t)$ is some arbitrary step function (not necessarily just a standard heaviside step function. Is there any easy/ logical way of solving this to find the integral limit t. It feels like it should be easy, as the integral of the step function is 'just' a piecewise linear function, but I'm really struggling to do this.

While I don't have any specific values in mind, I am most interested in the following:

1. The values of the n components of H(t) form a non-negative decreasing sequence.
2. $f(t) = kt$, where $k > 0$.
3. $c > 0$.

Under these conditions, I think there should be a unique solution (though would be interested to hear if I am wrong in assuming this!).

Comment: The integral of a step function is not "just a linear function", it's going to be a [piecewise linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function), which has as many pieces as the step function. That equation could have not just one, but many solutions. And I don't see an easy way without going into the gory details of what $f$ and $H$ are made of.

Comment: @user3733558 Sorry, yes. I know it's a piecewise linear function - I'll edit my question to remove that.

I don't know values for the step function or the function $f(t)$, this is more just a hypothetical scenario. However, I'm mostly interested in a situation where the step function is split into n components, with the value of each component strictly less than the previous. c is a positive value, and $f(t)$ has a positive derivative.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think you're right, there should be a unique solution somewhere in $[0,c/k]$. I don't see how to obtain a direct algebraic solution, but I would guess it's possible to cook up an algorithm... Hopefully someone else will have better ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof of existence and  uniqueness:

The solution exists because $g(t)=f(t) + \int_0^{t} H(u)du $ is a continuous function with $g(0)=0$ and $g(\frac{c}{k} +1) > c$, so by the intermediate value theorem there is at least a solution.

Now, say you have two solutions such that $t_2 > t_1$ then

$$f(t_1) + \int_0^{t_1} H(u)du = c$$

$$f(t_2) + \int_0^{t_2} H(u)du = f(t_2) + \int_0^{t_1} H(u)du +\int_{t_1}^{t_2} H(u)du  =  c$$

So subtracting  you get

$$f(t_2)-f(t_1)+\int_{t_1}^{t_2} H(u)du =0$$

But this is impossible because $ f(t_2)-f(t_1) >0$ and $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} H(u)du \geq 0$.

---

A method to solve the problem would be finding the component of $H(t)$ in which the solution lies and then calculate the solution from the starting point of that component. The algorithm to find the component is fast because $g(t)$ is a strictly increasing function so you can use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) with the values of $g(t)$ at the starting point of every component.

After you find the right component, say it starts (or the previous finishes) at $t_{a}$, you can calculate the solution exactly by just considering the difference $c-g(t_{a})$ and finding the right value in that component, which is easy because you need just to solve

$$(k+\lim_{t \to t_{a}^+}H(t))(t-t_{a}) =c-g(t_{a})$$

where $\lim_{t \to t_{a}^+}H(t)$ is the value at the starting point of the component.

So the solution is

$$t = t_a + \frac{c-g(t_{a})}{k+\lim_{t \to t_{a}^+}H(t)}$$

Comment: The definition of $g$ should be $g(t)=f(t) + \int_0^{t} H(t')dt'$ or perhaps better $g(t)=f(t) + \int_0^{t} H(u)du$. Not sure why the OP went with $t'$ for a variable name, bad idea IMO.

Comment: yes you are right, I edit with $u$

Answer (score 1):

For any function $h$ (not necessarily step),

$$f(t)+\int_0^t h(t)\,dt=c$$

is

$$f(t)+H(t)-H(0)=c$$ where $H$ is an antiderivative of $h$. To obtain $t$, you solve this ordinary, univariate equation.

If $h$ is a step function, its antiderivative is piecewise linear and continuous. You can solve the equation in every piece independently (and check that the solution(s) belong to the definition interval of the piece).

If $f$ is $kt$, then $t=0$ is always a solution. There can be a second solution if the values of $h$ are larger, then smaller than $k$.